# Pods are not restarting after initial minikube installation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am installing pods using helm on a minikube deployed in a Linux VM. Minikube is using the docker driver.

When I initially install the pod everything works but when minikube restarts the persistent volume is not accessible.

For example the helm chart for mariadb says it should be installed as the mysql user. minikube seems to ignore the helm chart and install it as the root user with 777 privilege. After the minikube restart restart the pod is started as mysql so the directory with the pid is not accessible and even if it was, the database tables are not visible.

Has anyone else seen this? The pods runs fine in a full K8S cluster so it seems to be a minikube issue.

I'm seeing the same issue with Mariadb, rabbitmq and key cloak

When it works

```
PersistentVolumeClaims Normal Scheduled <unknown> default-scheduler Successfully assigned default/mariadb-slave-0 to minikube Normal Pulled 2m46s kubelet, minikube Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3.23-debian-10-r44" already present on machine Normal Created 2m46s kubelet, minikube Created container mariadb Normal Started 2m46s kubelet, minikube Started container mariadb
```

After reboot

```
Name: mariadb-master-0 Namespace: default Priority: 0 Node: minikube/172.17.0.2 Start Time: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 14:43:21 -0400 Labels: app=mariadb chart=mariadb-7.6.1 component=master controller-revision-hash=mariadb-master-d95c68d44 release=mariadb statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mariadb-master-0 Annotations: <none> Status: Running IP: 172.18.0.7 IPs: IP: 172.18.0.7 Controlled By: StatefulSet/mariadb-master


Containers: mariadb: Container ID: docker://9fa565d16e4628655068eca1b585582ec8a136467f0120dae33bb91abf54eae4 Image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3.23-debian-10-r44 Image ID: docker-pullable://bitnami/mariadb@sha256:36bed267af44b9a8d4788a47b769aa4c126967c46d3fb80aefe9fc19d82aaeb4 Port: 3306/TCP Host Port: 0/TCP State: Waiting Reason: CrashLoopBackOff Last State: Terminated Reason: Error Exit Code: 1
```

dashboard logs

```
github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb mariadb 18:52:05.47 Submit issues and feature requests at github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues mariadb 18:52:05.47 mariadb 18:52:05.48 INFO ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup ** mariadb 18:52:05.49 INFO ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_/MARIADB_ env vars mariadb 18:52:05.49 INFO ==> Initializing mariadb database mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied
```

Comment: Hello @user3645171, could you please add `kubectl describe` of the mysql database pod after restart?

Comment: When it works it looks like:

Comment: PersistentVolumeClaims
  Normal   Scheduled         <unknown>  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mariadb-slave-0 to minikube
  Normal   Pulled            2m46s      kubelet, minikube  Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3.23-debian-10-r44" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           2m46s      kubelet, minikube  Created container mariadb
  Normal   Started           2m46s      kubelet, minikube  Started container mariadb

Comment: After the reboot:

Comment: Name:         mariadb-master-0
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/172.17.0.2
Start Time:   Wed, 08 Jul 2020 14:43:21 -0400
Labels:       app=mariadb
              chart=mariadb-7.6.1
              component=master
              controller-revision-hash=mariadb-master-d95c68d44
              release=mariadb
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mariadb-master-0
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.18.0.7
IPs:
  IP:           172.18.0.7
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mariadb-master

Comment: Containers:
  mariadb:
    Container ID:   docker://9fa565d16e4628655068eca1b585582ec8a136467f0120dae33bb91abf54eae4
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3.23-debian-10-r44
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bitnami/mariadb@sha256:36bed267af44b9a8d4788a47b769aa4c126967c46d3fb80aefe9fc19d82aaeb4
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1

Comment: The dashboard log says:

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb
mariadb 18:52:05.47 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues
mariadb 18:52:05.47 
mariadb 18:52:05.48 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
mariadb 18:52:05.49 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mariadb 18:52:05.49 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/14390#issuecomment-498150189), could you try to create a initContainer that prepare the volume with the right permissions? You can change it in [values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mariadb/values.yaml). If that won´t work could you try with chown as mentioned [here](https://techoverflow.net/2018/12/15/solving-bitnami-docker-redmine-cannot-create-directory-bitnami-mariadb-permission-denied/)? Let me know if that help.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments you should add [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that prepare the volume with the right permissions.

As far as I checked in stable mariadb chart this can be edited in the database chart [values.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mariadb/values.yaml#L53-L56).

---

There is description for this on bitnami mariadb [github](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mariadb#adjust-permissions-of-persistent-volume-mountpoint).

> **Adjust permissions of persistent volume mountpoint**
>
> As the image run as non-root by default, it is necessary to adjust the ownership of the persistent volume so that the container can write data into it.
>
> By default, the chart is configured to use Kubernetes Security Context to automatically change the ownership of the volume. However, this feature does not work in all Kubernetes distributions. As an alternative, this chart supports using an initContainer to change the ownership of the volume before mounting it in the final destination.
>
> You can enable this initContainer by setting **volumePermissions.enabled to true**.

---

Additionally there is related [github issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues/186) about that.

---

I hope this helps.